# Is there a way to go back to a previous state of an APFS Partition on an external drive?

Tags: mojave, external-disk, apfs

My question sums it up. I would like to go back in time on a partition on an external drive which is formatted on APFS. Decrypting a VirtualBox image, VBox crashed (as it does all the time in Mojave) and since then the disk image is corrupt. I was wondering if there's a way to go back to a previous state using APFS Snapshots.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you already save a snapsho? Are you attempting to return to one was automatically created? If neither, then no, you can't retrospectively go back to one that doesn't exist, that's what Time Machine is for.

Comment: The real answer here is, don't use VirtualBox.  It's worth everything you paid for it.

Comment: No I didn’t manually create a snapshot. Is there a way to configure APFS to create automatic snapshots? I don’t use time machine on my external drives, honestly. It’s also not the default behaviour. But might change that from now on.

Comment: Regarding VirtualBox, I have observes that it’s extremely unrealiable under Mojave and fails a lot. However it’s also depending on the computer model. On a Macbook Air 2017 it works fine. Maybe it has to do with Resolutions? Also I would love to use Whonix with Parallels, but I haven’t found a way to make it work.

Comment: APFS has transactional copy-on-write behaviour, so, in theory, you can revert to a previous, recent state, but there is no official mechanism for doing so.